# Pandas series dt.period('M') not converting to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following line of code:

```
open_tks_per_day['Created_year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(open_tks_per_day['Created']).dt.to_period('M')
```

what this does is extract the year and the month from a datetime and stores it on a column called Created_year_month. the problem is that this column is an object but when I try to convert it to  datetime with this code:

```
open_tks_per_day['Created_year_month'] = open_tks_per_day['Created_year_month'].astype('datetime64')
```

i get the following error:

```
TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime
```

the whole aim of this is to be able to plot the `Created_year_month` variable against a categorical variable using a stripplot as if i plot it using the whole date I get too many data points so i have figured that if i aggregate the data points by month and year I will get less data points which makes my plt look much tidier.

Here is some sample data:

```
Number  Created     Created_date    Created_year_month
2018-01-16 16:23:21     2018-01-16  2018-01
2018-01-11 17:51:18     2018-01-11  2018-01
2018-01-12 13:03:50     2018-01-12  2018-01
2018-01-11 13:28:55     2018-01-11  2018-01
2018-01-04 09:58:36     2018-01-04  2018-01
2018-01-23 09:19:36     2018-01-23  2018-01
2019-04-09 10:50:54     2019-04-09  2019-04
2019-04-08 19:22:49     2019-04-08  2019-04
2019-04-09 12:34:24     2019-04-09  2019-04
2019-04-09 17:22:10     2019-04-09  2019-04
2019-04-09 09:58:52     2019-04-09  2019-04
2019-04-08 20:08:01     2019-04-08  2019-04
2019-04-09 18:40:13     2019-04-09  2019-04
2019-04-09 19:29:04     2019-04-09  2019-04
2019-04-10 02:43:15     2019-04-10  2019-04
2019-04-10 03:04:36     2019-04-10  2019-04
2019-04-10 03:12:02     2019-04-10  2019-04
2019-04-10 03:49:19     2019-04-10  2019-04
2019-04-10 04:46:04     2019-04-10  2019-04
2019-04-10 05:18:24     2019-04-10  2019-04
```

here is how the plot is looking at the moment which is not great:
[image]

Comment: Please share the sample dataset for experiment

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou all done. please can you remove the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because a period is not the same as a datetime. In your question, I'm not sure what output you want. For example, is it the counts of the objects by month, the sum, the mean, etc.? Regardless, there is a built in function that can help you--[pandas.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html).

Assumptions: I'm assuming you want the count of open tickets per day. I'm also assuming there is some field that you can count. If not you can always add one with `open_tks_per_day['is_ticket'] = 1`. For the rest of my example, I'm going to use `is_ticket` as the thing you are counting.

Assuming you want the count of open tickets by month, you could do:

```
 res = open_tks_per_day['Created'].groupby(Grouper(key='Created', freq='M')).count().reset_index()

 plt.plot(res['Created'],res['is_ticket']) # Again making assumptions here
```

Disclaimer: There is no sample data so I couldn't test my code.